# Why jquery scroll function load well only after the second or third time of use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery scroll function loads well only second and third time use. 
After page is loaded its not working well. the transition-duration what I set up is working step by step, not smoothly like after the second or third time.

I use `$(window).on('load', function() { ... });` function, and all script tag are before the closing body tag.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

            // navbar scroll things
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("shrink");
      $(".navbar").removeClass("bg-transparent");
      $(".navbar img").attr("src", "img/logo_fekete.png");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("shrink");
      $(".navbar img").attr("src", "img/logo_feher.png");
    }
  });

  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $(".scroll").on("click", function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 850, function(){
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });

});
```

the actual results can see there:
http://bgydesigntest.000webhostapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jQuery ready()` method instead. This will allow your jQuery methods to be loaded as soon as your HTML document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            // navbar scroll things
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("shrink");
      $(".navbar").removeClass("bg-transparent");
      $(".navbar img").attr("src", "img/logo_fekete.png");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("shrink");
      $(".navbar img").attr("src", "img/logo_feher.png");
    }
  });

  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $(".scroll").on("click", function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();
      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 850, function(){
        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });

});
```

Comment: It's better, thank you! I've also made the second logo's size smaller so it's loads faster. This way everything work fine.

Comment: great...glad to know that